# Access SharePoint List using a pair of email id / password without using a browser login in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, botframework

I am trying to access a SharePoint List using email id and password, without using a browser login inside Microsoft Bot framework code in C#.

Although I can fetch a few files like ".csv", ".js" , I am unable to access the SharePoint Calendar.

If anyone has encountered similar issues before, please help.

Code to access SharePoint:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(SERVICE_URL))
{
   SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
   for (int i = 0; i<HASH_CODE.Length; i++)
   {
       securePassword.AppendChar(HASH_CODE[i]);
   }             

   SharePointOnlineCredentials creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(USER, securePassword);
   context.Credentials = creds;

   context.Load(context.Web.Lists);

   Web site = context.Web;
   ListCollection listColl = site.Lists;
   FolderCollection collFolder = site.Folders;
   context.Load(collFolder);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   foreach (Folder folder in collFolder)
   {
      context.Load(folder.Files);
      context.ExecuteQuery();
      FileCollection fileCol = folder.Files;
      foreach (var file in folder.Files)
      {
         if (file.Name == "Calendar.aspx")
         {
             File attachment = file;
             string filename = attachment.Name;
             var serverFilePath = attachment.ServerRelativeUrl;
             DownloadIt(serverFilePath, path, context, filename);
         }

      }
      context.ExecuteQuery();
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the code you are using to access the SharePoint Calendar.

Comment: Code to access SharePoint: